# VBA - How Can I Get Randomize String Array To Work?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Overview: I am pasting many words on separate lines into text box: txtWordRandomizer. Then, move each line into the string array. I need to shuffle/randomize the array, but can't seem to get it to work.

I got the bottom Sub, ShuffleArray(), here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShuffleArray.aspx 
...and it seems to be what everyone references when talking about shuffling/randomizing an array.

I get Error: **Type Mismatch: array or user-defined type expected** on calling ShuffleArrayInPlace(), but thought this was for randomizing a string array. Do I somehow need to translate the string array into a variant array?

Or, any other suggestion on how I can get this to work?

```
    Private Sub btnRandomize_Click()

        Dim strRandoms() As String
        strRandoms() = Split(Me.txtWordRandomizer.Value, vbCrLf)
        strRandoms() = ShuffleArray(strRandoms())

    End Sub    


Function ShuffleArray(InArray() As Variant) As Variant()

' This function returns the values of InArray in random order. The original
' InArray is not modified.

    Dim N As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim J As Long
    Dim Arr() As Variant


    Randomize
    L = UBound(InArray) - LBound(InArray) + 1
    ReDim Arr(LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray))
    For N = LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray)
        Arr(N) = InArray(N)
    Next N
    For N = LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray)
        J = CLng(((UBound(InArray) - N) * Rnd) + N)
        Temp = InArray(N)
        InArray(N) = InArray(J)
        InArray(J) = Temp
    Next N
    ShuffleArray = Arr
End Function
```

Comment: `ShuffleArrayInPlace` is not a function (and not is called `ShuffleArray` either - that is a *different* method on the same page you linked...)  The sub takes a variant array, but you can change that to `InArray() As String` and it will still work fine.  You'd call it using `ShuffleArrayInPlace strRandoms` - after that call `strRandoms` should now be shuffled

Comment: Okay, apologies - I wrote this while tired.

I have updated the actual function I am using. I had the wrong one. Also, I edited in the full error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some quick testing, the `ShuffleArray` function in the posted link doesn't actually return a randomized array. Since you're keeping your array in the `strRandoms` variable, you can use the in-place function anyways (the in-place function will also be more efficient, since it doesn't have to create and populate an entirely new array when called).

When calling the function and passing your array as an argument, don't include parentheses after your array. So do this:

```
ShuffleArrayInPlace a
' Or this:
Call ShuffleArrayInPlace(a)
```

However, in order to do this successfully, you have to slightly change the method signature of `ShuffleArrayInPlace` from this (as it is now):

```
Sub ShuffleArrayInPlace(InArray() As Variant)
```

to this:

```
Sub ShuffleArrayInPlace(InArray As Variant)
```

Note that the parentheses after the `InArray` are gone. Why do this?

Originally, with the parentheses, the function is expecting an array of `Variant` values. However, the `split` function returns an array of **string** values. By changing the method signature to remove the parentheses, you're basically saying you can pass anything to the function (a string array, a variant array, or even something that's not an array at all). Because of this, you could update `ShuffleArrayInPlace` to raise an error if the argument is not an array (using the [IsArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isarray-function) function).

Speaking of refactoring: While the algorithm the `ShuffleArrayInPlace` uses to shuffle an array is clear, it's not necessarily the best one. I would review the [Fisher-Yates](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) shuffle, and try implementing it yourself in VBA as an exercise.

---

## So, in summary...

- When calling a function that takes an array as an argument, don't put parentheses after the array: `Call ShuffleArrayInPlace(strRandoms)
- Use `ShuffleArrayInPlace`, not `ShuffleArray`.
- Change the `ShuffleArrayInPlace` function so that `InArray` is a `Variant`, not `Variant()`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub btnRandomize_Click()

    Dim strRandoms() As String
    strRandoms = Split("A|B|C|D|E", "|")
    strRandoms = ShuffleArray(strRandoms)

    Debug.Print Join(strRandoms, ", ")

End Sub


Function ShuffleArray(InArray() As String) As String()
    Dim N As Long, Temp As Variant
    Dim J As Long, Arr() As String

    Randomize

    'make a copy of the array
    ReDim Arr(LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray))
    For N = LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray)
        Arr(N) = InArray(N)
    Next N
    'shuffle the copy
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        J = CLng(((UBound(Arr) - N) * Rnd) + N)
        Temp = Arr(N)
        Arr(N) = Arr(J)
        Arr(J) = Temp
    Next N
    ShuffleArray = Arr 'return the shuffled copy
End Function
```